# Error al imprimir en pantalla tkinter python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Hay un problema a la hora de iniciar la función ¿podrían ayudarme?

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import *
import getpass
import os

usuario = getpass.getuser()   
ventana = Frame(height=400,width=400,background="black")
ventana.pack()

def elegir():
    archivo=askopenfile(mode="r",initialdir="C:/Users/%s/Desktop" % usuario,
        filetypes=(("Documento word","*.doc",),("ALL FILES","*.*.*")))
    directorio = os.path.split(archivo)[0] 
    print(directorio)

boton_eleg = Button(ventana,text="SELECCIONE EL ARCHIVO",command=elegir).place(x=10,y=220)      

ventana.mainloop()
```

Quiero que se imprima solo la ruta ,pero me encuentro con el problema en la consola.

Agradeceria una ayuda.

Comment: `askopenfile` abre un fichero. Si lo que quieres es obtener una ruta, utiliza `askopenfilename`

Comment: No, lo que necesito es imprimir la ruta del archivo que elija con el askopenfile

Answer (score 0):

`askopenfile` retorna un objeto de tipo `file` o `None` si no se selecciona o no se puede abrir el archivo. Simplemente no puedes aplicar `os.path.split()` sobre ninguno de los dos.

Para conseguir la ruta puedes simplemente acceder al atributo `name` del objeto `file`:

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import *
import getpass
import os

usuario = getpass.getuser()
ventana = Frame(height=400,width=400,background="black")
ventana.pack()

def elegir():
    archivo=askopenfile(mode="r", initialdir="C:/Users/%s/Desktop" % usuario,
        filetypes=(("Documento word","*.doc",),("ALL FILES","*.*.*")))
    directorio = ''
    if archivo:
        directorio = os.path.split(archivo.name)[0]
        print directorio

boton_eleg = Button(ventana,text="SELECCIONE EL ARCHIVO",command=elegir).place(x=10,y=220)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Si la ruta es por ejemplo:

> C:/Users/Alguien/Desktop/documento.doc

`directorio` contiene al aplicar `os.path.split()[0]`:

> C:/Users/Alguien/Desktop

Como te ha comentado Chema Cortés podria ser más simple usar `askopenfilename` que ya te retorna la ruta del archivo y luego lo abres como cualquier archivo en Python usando [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open).